# Most efficient way to identify values not present in a table using SQL

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I currently need to search a table of items to validate a list of items entered by the user.
The table of items contains a unique primary key for each item, called ItemId (which corresponds to the values entered by the user).
Given a table with 10000 (ten-thousand) rows, what would be the most efficient way to search the ItemId column and determine if ANY of the items the user entered did not exist in the table?

For example, given the table:

```
ItemId       Color      Price
 1000         Blue       3.00  
 1001          Red       4.00  
 1003        Green       1.25
```

And the user enters the following:
    1000
    1001
    1002

I'd like to throw up an error to alert the user that one of the items (1002) is invalid.  It is not a requirement for me to specifically identify the item that is invalid, only that one or more items does not exist in the table.  I've tried using IF NOT EXISTS, as well as EXCEPT but I'm not getting a feel for a 'best practice' in terms of efficiency.  Normally, I would examine the execution plan, but I don't really know where to start.  I would greatly appreciate any and all suggestions!

Comment: best combination is EXISTS clause with clustered index on itemid field.

Comment: if itemid is a pk, and theres a clustered index on it in the table, i doubt theres a better way than using a simple where clause (which is probably what you are using within the IF NOT EXISTS)

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to take the user's input (1000, 1001...) and check it against what is in the table? I would try WHERE ItemID NOT IN (user entered list)

Comment: You could set up a foreign-key constraint and then catch the FK error when you try to update/insert/whatever. Let SQL do the check for you

Comment: how do you pass the user entered values to sql server? to a proc? or do they get inserted into a table first? ideally you'd want them in a table, then you can do a select WHERE [entry] NOT IN [items table].

Comment: @YavgenyP That's what I'm thinking.  Basically, a SELECT 1 FROM ITEMS WHERE ItemId NOT IN (SELECT ItemId from User-Entered-Items)

Comment: @njk That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Given your comment, sounds like I'm on the right track.  Thanks!

Comment: @SeanW The data comes from an XML file that's uploaded to an ftp server at certain intervals throughout the day.  The item list is then parsed from the XML file in a stored procedure.

Comment: Chris's answer looks fairly optimised. What I was getting at is, if you pass the user entries in one by one, as you would with Chris' method below, or if you can prepopulate a temp table with all the entries at once, then do the check. i.e. is there a min/max number of user choices submitted? if it's one at a time, use Chris' method. If it's always 3, then that might change things. If it's any number between 0 and 100 - you perhaps don't want to run a proc 100 times. Rather use a method that gets the user data in the DB first, then does a single check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Chris' answer in that using a TVP is a good way of passing in the user supplied values but would make the following changes.

Declare the TVP with a Primary Key

```
CREATE TYPE ItemTableType AS TABLE 
( ItemId INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `OUTER JOIN ... NULL`. This is implemented as an efficient anti semi join. The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint and `PRIMARY KEY` should give sufficient information to the optimiser to choose the best join strategy for the size of both tables.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   @Items i
                      WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                         FROM   dbo.MyItemTable it
                                         WHERE  i1.ItemId = it.ItemId)) THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

`OUTER JOIN ... NULL` can end up outer joining all rows then eliminating the `NOT NULL` ones with a filter afterwards which is less efficient (Example of that at bottom of [this article](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/t-sql-tuesday-023-flip-side-of-join.html)), also see [Left outer join vs NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a Table-Valued parameter in my stored procedure, then simply LEFT JOIN to the table and look for NULL.

```
CREATE TYPE ItemTableType AS TABLE 
( ItemId INT);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetItems
    @Items ItemTableType READONLY
AS 

SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM dbo.MyItemTable i1 
           LEFT JOIN @Items i2 ON i1.ItemId = @i2.ItemId 
           WHERE i2.ItemId IS NULL)

    RAISERROR('Item does not exist', 16, 1)
ELSE
    SELECT i1.*
    FROM dbo.MyItemTable i1
    JOIN @Items i2 on i1.ItemId = @i2.ItemId

GO
```

The other possibility I can think of is to perform a count on the end result.

To perform the count:

```
DECLARE @CommaCount INT

SET @CommaCount = (select len(@ItemIds)-len(replace(@ItemIds,',','')))
```

Then when you perform the SELECT, just compare the result to the count:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.MyItemTable
WHERE ItemId IN (@ItemIds)

IF(@@ROWCOUNT != @CommaCount)
    RAISERROR('Item does not exist', 16, 1)
```